# Can someone make me a simple circuit?

Tags: power-supply, power

I have a **power supply** that can output 3V, 4.5V, 6V, 7.5V, 9V or 12V and **24 white LEDs** 3,2V - 3,5V (I think I'll need **resistors** as well, right?).
I need a circuit that lights all LEDs and uses as less power as needed.

If you can help me that would be great.

Thank you

Comment: What is the current capability of your power supply at each voltage?

Comment: I'm not sure how to know that :/ so I'll post what is written on the power supply:
INPUT: 230V ~ 50Hz
POWER: 12,5W
CURRENT: 500mA6VA(max)

Comment: Look on the Power supply case. Or point us to an online listing or photo.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically, you want the same exact circuit as simple LED Strips have. Multiple parallel segments of 3 leds in series with a resistor.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fY9KVB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

24 leds, divided by 3, that's 8 segments, at 16~20mA each is only 160mA at most, which your supply can provide no problem.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but noob question.. Why is R1 connected directly to the power supply and R2 is not.

Comment: @jcamilo I pulled the picture from an old answer from another question asking exactly that. Basically, it doesn't matter where the resistor is in series, it will limit the current just the same.

Comment: Oh ok. Is it possible to divide the 24 leds by 2 and have 12 segments?

Comment: @jcamilo yep. Just adjust the resistor and voltage. The formula is `(Source Voltage - Forward Voltage) / Current = Resistance`. Two leds at ~3.3V and 20mA, `7.5V - 6.6 / .02` = 45Ω.

Comment: Passerby - You might want to redo your numbers. That's a 12 volt supply.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast it's a variable supply with selectable voltage settings. Since op wants 8x 2 led segments, its better to choose 7.5v instead of 9v or 12v.